# laravel - sqs queue delayed

Tags: laravel, queue, amazon-sqs

i've a problem with SQS Queue,

when i run the queue it will lounch but will not sent the email, i cant understand why.

```
// UserController.php
 public function checkValiationAccount($user)
  {
    // Avvio il Job di verifica dell'utente validato entro 2 minuti (DELAY GESTITO DALLA QUEUE DI SQS)
    $job = (new ValidationAccountJob($user))
      ->onQueue(env('SQS_QUEUE_ACCOUNT'))
      ->onConnection('sqs-fifo-account');
    $this->dispatch($job);
  }
```

this is the ValidationAccountJob

```
  public function handle(User $user)
  {
    // SENT EMAIL IF USER IS PENDING
    if ($user->status == 'PENDING') {
      Mail::send('mail.user.userValidation', ['user' => $user], function ($m) use ($user) {
        $m->from('noreply@example.it');
        $m->to(App::environment() == 'production' ? $user->email : env('TEST_EMAIL'), $user->name)
          ->subject($user->name . 'EMAIL SUBJECT');
      });
      return true;
    }
  return false;
  }
```

the SQS Queue Fifo is delayed with 2 minutes.
Run run but nothing append

> {"uuid":"fa0099ec-f7b6-4a10-aada-a546ead2d5a1","displayName":"App\Jobs\ValidationAccountJob","job":"Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler@call","maxTries":null,"maxExceptions":null,"delay":null,"timeout":null,"timeoutAt":null,"data":{"commandName":"App\Jobs\ValidationAccountJob","command":"O:29:\"App\Jobs\ValidationAccountJob\":8:{s:3:\"job\";N;s:10:\"connection\";s:16:\"sqs-fifo-account\";s:5:\"queue\";s:39:\"testonlineValidationAccountQueue.fifo\";s:15:\"chainConnection\";N;s:10:\"chainQueue\";N;s:5:\"delay\";N;s:10:\"middleware\";a:0:{}s:7:\"chained\";a:0:{}}"}}

Comment: I couldn't get "exact" the problem, it sends to sqs but your application doesn't consume it? It sends to sqs, application consume & process it but email not delivered ?

Comment: in **artisan queue:work** nothing append, but job in AWS seems to be running; and email is not sent

Comment: i think you are not listening/working with the correct config, `artisan queue:work sqs-fifo-account --queue=your-queue-name` - you may retry to push and listen with that.

Comment: also don't use `env('SQS_QUEUE_ACCOUNT')` outside of config files, it may cause unforeseen consequences https://prnt.sc/st4zvo